# Bootstrap scaffolding: Table in some row lie one under the other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make the bootstrap scaffolding to work. I have two `table`s, one left, one right, both inside a `row`. Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/83/).

For some reason the tables appear one *under* the other. How can I get both tables to be at the same hight?

Comment: Yuck! Did you paste that code from Word or something? Doing what you want is extremely easy in Bootstrap, but I gave up trying to wade through your unformatted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to use `offset 8` with your second table, thats 12 on its own.  If one table is a `span4` and the other is a `span4` they will sit side by side with a `span4` remaining...

each row consumes a spans of 12 columns, you had 4 in your first table, 8 between the tables, and another 4 for your second table.. making 16 columns, and so, two rows (16/12)

if you use `span4` plus `offset3 span4` you get 11 columns! well within the 12 column default limit :)

so if you wanted you could use `offset2` for some space between them

http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/84/

Answer (score 0):

Noob answering here, but I think you need to have your two tables in separate `<div class="span2">` tags if you're already using a `row` div tag.

EDIT: Wait, shoot, got it wrong. Is it the very end has a typo `diV` with a capital V?